# Examples and exercises about the interpretation method in logic

Tags: reference-request, logic, first-order-logic

I am a beginner student of logic and I am experiencing some trouble at finding interpretations that help me prove dependence/independence of axioms, consistency, as well as the independence of primitive symbols (relations and operators).

I just seem to do very bad in dealing with these kinds of situations. So, I'm looking for material with plenty of exercises and examples of interpretations (preferentially arithmetical) applied to logical structures. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can see : Stephen Simpson, [Mathematical Logic](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/logic.pdf) (2013) and Derek Goldrei, [Propositional and Predicate Calculus : A Model of Argument](https://books.google.it/books?id=B7UGnBbb2JoC&printsec=frontcover) (2005).